# How to use separate stores for each app instance on the same page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a fairly complex VueJS2 application, that uses a vuex store.

Up until now, everything worked perfectly. Now I have to change the application to support multiple instances on one page.
It should be dynamic, which means the customer should be able to insert as many instances as he wants by simply adding the required HTML code. This is already possible since we use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-custom-element

The main problem of course is Vuex. there is, quite understandable, only one instance. And since the application instances are all the same component, I can not easily add separate Vuex instances.

To paint a clearer picture:

The Vuex store is being generated like this:

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    store: () => ({
/* the data */
    })
/* modules, getters, mutations, and simmilar */
  })
}
```

The VueJS application is being generated normally:

app.vue:

```
export default {
  store: createStore(),
  /* Other stuff */
}
```

main.js:

```
Vue.customElement('my-app', app)
```

I know I could refactor the application to use dynamically registered modules, but it would be quite a big change and I am hoping for an easier solution, at least temporarily until we refactor the application.

Is there a quicker solution than dynamic modules? I am grateful for every suggestion.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution. Maybe give the Vuex doc API section a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I believe it is somewhat hacky, but it works.

If you plan to have multiple application instances on the same page I strongly recommend that you design your VueJS application accordingly. However, if you are in a pickle like I was, this might be a quick solution, that works well.

First, you need a function, that returns a store. If you export your store directly you will still use the same instance!

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    store: () => ({
/* the data */
    })
/* modules, getters, mutations, and simmilar */
  })
}
```

In your main module, you have to create and inject a separate store into each app instance. The best way to do this is to create and inject a store in the "beforeCreate" hook:

```
export default {
    // ...
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$store = createStore();
    },
};
```

I found this solution on Github:
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/414#issue-184491718